# Full width of input field in a inline-block

Tags: css

my goal is to have a size of 100% of the input field inside a block.
(I use a inline-block). I tried this way but without success.

html

```
<div id="search-blk">
  <p>
    <label>One</label>
    <label class="field">
    <select name="obj" id="obj" class="fieldmax">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
    </select>
    </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

css

```
#search-blk p {
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 400px;
}

#search-blk p label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
}

input, textarea, select { 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  font-size: 10px; 
  padding: 3px; 
  width: 200px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-right: 0px; 
  box-sizing: border-box;   
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;  
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  background: #fdfdfd;
}

.field {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}   

.fieldmax {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybx6z/1/)

you can do this? how could I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you are using `display: inline-block`, then comment out the white-spaces otherwise you get unwanted space in-between. See demo.
2. You are wrapping your `select` inside a `label`. Why? Just use a `label` as-is with a `for` attribute, if required.
3. No need for complicating the markup by introducing an extra `p` inside that `div`.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ybx6z/4/***

*Markup*:

```
<div id="search-blk">
    <label for="obj">One</label><!-- Comment out this whitespace
    --><select name="obj" id="obj" class="fieldmax">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

*Relevant CSS*:

```
#search-blk label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
}

input, textarea, select { 
    display: inline-block;
    ...
}

.fieldmax {
    width: 90%;
}
```

**Update**:

If you want to keep your `label` to be fixed width in pixels (and yet want the `select` to expand up to the remaining width), then use `display: table` and `table-cell` on the container `div` and elements respectively.

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ybx6z/8/***

*Relevant CSS*:

```
#search-blk {
    display: table;
}

#search-blk label {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 64px;
}

.fieldmax {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

***Demo 3: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ybx6z/9/***

Here you have two `label`s and one `select`. First `label` is auto width as per the content. Second `label` is fixed width. The `select` is flexible with 100% width (remaining available).

Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you, but it would be possible to have the fixed width (100px and 300px) of label and input?

Comment: @PaoloRossi: Updated the answer. But, you cannot have fixed width on all elements and yet occupy 100% width. You have to keep at least one element flexible.

Comment: @PaoloRossi: Added the third demo for your better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your time! But I've a problem when I tried to add <p> and <form> http://jsfiddle.net/ybx6z/11/ . could you give me a help yet? thanks

Comment: @PaoloRossi: I don't get it: 
*(1)* Why did you remove the `display:table` and `table-cell`? As I explained you above, it is needed to expand elements to width. `inline-block` won't help. 
*(2)* Why are you adding `p`? Please use `div` to layout your elements. `p` is paragraph and should not be used for layouts. 
I have updated your fiddle, see here: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ybx6z/12/**